# How to concatenate two arrays into 1 single array using java?

Tags: java, algorithm

concatenate two arrays into single dimensional array?

For example:-

**Take two arrays**

```
Array1[10] = {3,3,3}

Array2[10] ={3,2,1}
```

**output**

```
Array3[] = {33,32,31}
```

How will I get this output ?

Comment: What have you tried already? Seriously, someone will probably answer anyway for the rep points but you should have a go and then ask if your attempt isn't working.

Comment: what's the data type of element of the array??

Comment: Have you heard about this Java thing called loops and String concatenation?

Comment: try arrayutils  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

Comment: That's not concatenating arrays. That's creating an array concatenating (or something) the entries from two source arrays.

Comment: I have a question to this, is stack overflow become a free debugging tool online. Share what have you done, rather than putting questions online like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a for-loop an iterate over `Array1` and `Array2`
2. Do `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Array1[i])+String.valueOf(Array2[i]));`
3. Fill the `Array3` in the for-loop with the calculated valued.

That's it.

```
    int[] Array1 = new int[] {3,3,3};
    int[] Array2 = new int[] {3,2,1};
    int[] Array3 = new int[Array2.length];

    for(int i = 0; i<Array1.length; i++) {
        Array3[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Array1[i])+String.valueOf(Array2[i]));
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Array3[] = {33,32,31}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not concatenating arrays, because that would look more like:

```
Array3[] = {3,3,3,3,2,1}
```

What you want to do is to concatenate each element inside the array, which is a different process entirely, and one you could accomplish with a simple for loop.

```
if(array1 is the same size as array2)
{
    define array3 = new array[array1.length];

    for(int x = 0 to array1.length)
    {
        array3[x] = array1[x] + array2[x]. 
    }
}
```

This is pseudocode, which I provide when the question doesn't contain any code. It's up to you to figure out how to turn this into Java code, although that isn't too difficult. You'll also notice I'm using the `+` operator for concatenation. I'm assuming your values are `String` type. If they're not, then get creative, using the `Integer.parseInt` method.

Comment: it will be a sum of the integers, not a concatenation

Comment: It will be a concatenation depending on the array type as noted. That is pseudocode.

Comment: I anticipated this, which is why I wrote *"You'll also notice I'm using the + operator for concatenation. I'm assuming your values are String type. If they're not, then get creative, using the Integer.parseInt method."*. All this code does is explain the core principles. Implementation details are up to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Quick hint: to concatenate two integer values simply use:

```
array3[i] = array1[i] + "" + array2[i];
```

The result will be transformed to `Srting` because the second operand `""` is a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< Array1.length; i++)
        {
            Array3[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.format("{0}{1}", Array1[i],Array2[i])); 
        }
```